# Can a university suspend a student even when he has left university?

Tags: graduation

If a student is supposed to be punished with something like suspension, but he has finished academic requirement and left the campus(not officially graduated yet). Can the university still do anything to him?

Answer (score 9):

Yes. The university can revoke the degree. [Example](http://blogs.nature.com/news/2014/10/schon-loses-last-appeal-against-phd-revocation.html), which was about a PhD degree being revoked because the student later went on to commit academic fraud.

If the student hasn't graduated then the university can also withhold graduation, which as far as I know is quite common. For example if the student has outstanding library loans, the university can withhold graduation until the loans are settled.

Comment: Then what about something like suspension? I mean he has left the campus

Comment: @Rapidturtle I don't understand. In this context isn't suspension similar to withholding graduation?

Comment: @Rapidturtle Really depends on the cause of the suspension, i.e. how much the student ticked off the administration to get suspended. They could almost certainly withhold graduation or officially granting the degree if they were so inclined. Administration has pretty wide latitude in such matters, and the more serious the behavior that caused the suspension (according to the school, not the student), the more likely they will play hard ball.

Comment: Actually, I think for unpaid bills most universities wouldn't "withhold graduation" per se but not give the student the diploma and refuse to send transcripts until financial obligations were met. And revoking degrees is normally applied only for the most serious infractions, such as the fraud you cite.

Comment: IME, some universities have "conduct" suspensions that are of very little relevance to someone off-campus, and primarily affect undergraduates. For example, one can be "suspended" from intramural sports or from living in a dorm. At my alma mater, this mostly happened due to drug violations, and *didn't affect academic progress at all*, as the *point* of them was to encourage students to *concentrate more on academics*.

Comment: @RobertColumbia Didn't students take drug get expelled?

Comment: @Rapidturtle not always, no. Almost everyone tried drugs at one point or another. If this was your tenth offense, or you were caught selling, then yes, that could get you expelled.